# Convert kj::Promise<kj::Exception> to kj::Promise<void>

Tags: promise, capnproto, kj

I can return a `kj::Exception` where a `kj::Promise` is expected, like so:

```cpp
kj::Promise<void> someFunc() {
  return KJ_EXCEPTION(FAILED, "some description");
}
```

But what if I end up having a `kj::Promise<kj::Exception>` in a place where I don't have a `waitScope`? For instance:

```cpp
kj::Promise<void> someFunc(kj::Promise<void> somePromise) {
  return somePromise.then([]() {
    return KJ_EXCEPTION(FAILED, "some description");
  });
}
```

There my compiler complains that there is no valid conversion between `kj::Promise<kj::Exception>` and `kj::Promise<void>`.

Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little surprised that I didn't prohibit `Promise<Exception>` in the first place; using such a construction likely leads to a lot of problems.

You can avoid it in your code by explicitly declaring the return type of the lambda to be `Promise<void>`, i.e.:

```
  return somePromise.then([]() -> kj::Promise<void> {
```

Comment: Yes that does it! Thanks a lot!